# Downgrade to watchOS1 - watchKit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

Up until today the project containing the watchOS1 worked perfectly. But all of a sudden i encountered the following error

> "The operation couln't be completed (LaunchServicesError 0.)"

In addition Xcode asked me to commit to some changes on the project, which i did.

What happened - it changed the `watchKit` deployment and debugging target to **watchOS2** without any possibility of reversal. 
I currently employ the basic `openParentApp` method which is deprecated in **watchOS2** and i have no intention of making an update for WatchConnectivity framework at the moment. As you've probably already guessed Xcode went bonkers and threw a bunch of errors because of that.

So my only goal right now is to downgrade to OS1 - since there is no SDK or even an option available in the target settings - how do i do it?

Thank you.

Comment: that's reasonable. but how do devs deploy both watchOS1 and OS2 in one package from Xcode 7 ? there are accounts of people being able to do so @EricD.

Comment: Google is really good for finding existing answers. I searched "Xcode 7 watchOS 1" and this was the first link.

Comment: @Fogmeister that's actually a different question. I'm asking about "downgrading", not "creating a new project".